# How to get better response on a problem (specific case study) and suggestions from mathematicians?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Why not enough response for this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/208867/14414).  I guess there is too little interest in classical Fourier analysis. I have given enough motivation, which is about proving a possibly new result in Fourier analysis, that too after a hundred years. Unless we disprove/prove we don't know, so I though it would generate enough interest too at least take notice and giving possible hints, just for the heck of it. I can't think of giving any better motivation unless of course I put a million dollar prize on top of it.

One comment comes, that too nothing to do with the current problem but suggesting to quit all this and go study a different subject. Duh, can't ask for worse!

Comment: I have no idea whether a not a reasonable question is hiding in there, but as things stand it is way too long.  Successful questions on MO tend to be succinct enough that an expert can immediately figure out whether or not they are interested.  If it requires a lot of work to just understand what you are asking, few people will do it.

Comment: @AndyPutman : Thank you for the valueble feedback. I have to put the exact question succinctly in the first paragraph, draw a line, and then keep the current stuff (motivation/goal etc) later, explicitly saying that "read further only if you re interested in the motivation and this is not really needed for answering the question". I am editing... (My main question is really not that long!)

Comment: @AndyPutman : done editing.

Comment: @AndyPutman : Let me know how it sounds now.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/210787/14414

Answer (score 5):

Your question is quite long.
You do provide a lot of background, but at the expense of making it slow to find the actual question.
I would suggest isolating the one thing you want to ask and provide a little background.
You can provide more motivation if someone asks.
If you want to ask several things related to your problem, ask several separate questions.
That is, if you can rephrase your key question in a shorter form, do so.

The content of the question does seem reasonable.
There are lots and lots of little open problems to be solved and new results to be shown.
Potential for a little new result alone does not motivate many mathematicians to take a look at it, especially if it's too far from their expertise.

Your remark "One comment comes, that too nothing to do with the current problem but suggesting to quit all this and go study a different subject." is not an faithful description of the comment you received.
It refers you to a tool that you might find useful.

Comment: I can't cut it short.

Comment: I have edited to put the question straight forward at the top (self-contained) and pushed all the other motivation stuff to the bottom. The reader need not even go to the motivation unless he is curious. Please let me know how it sounds now?

Comment: @RajeshD, it looks much better now. The main question at the beginning has tolerable length and the long extra part is clearly marked.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1348843/2987

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/210787/14414